# For what value of $a$ equation $\cos2x +7 = a(2-\sin x)$ can have a real solution

Tags: trigonometry

> **Problem**: For what value of $a$ equation $cos2x +7 = a(2-\sin x)$ can have a real solution
>
> In answer  value of $a$ should be in  the interval like $a \in(2,4)$ etc.
>
> **Solution**: $\cos2x +7 = a(2-\sin x)$
>
> $1-2 \sin^2x +7 = a(2-\sin x)$
>
> $2 \sin^2x -a\sin x +2a-8 =0$
>
> for real roots $ B^2 -4AC \geq0$

Can we get answer by the above method ?

Comment: Yes, but additionaly, the quadratic equation has to have at least one real root in the interval [-1,1].

Comment: After that I have no idea "how to get answer"

Comment: Set sin x =t and solve the quadratic equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the quadratic equation $2t^2-at+2a-8=0$ has two real roots $t_1=2$ and $t_2=(a-4)/2$. Therefore the trig equation will have real roots if $-1 \le (a-4)/2 \le 1$ that is 
$-2 \le a-4 \le 2$ $2 \le a \le 6$

Comment: but ans is given $a \in [2,6]$

Comment: yes I corrected the calculation.